# Ошибка при передачи аргументов в callback

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, callback

Я имею некий опыт написания `js` кода, но все же, я всегда имею проблемы при передачи аргументов в асинхронную функцию, и часто так бывает, что переданные мною аргументы уже не существуют и/или имеют значение `undefined`, и тут появляются различные проблемы. Так же, частой проблемой, после выполненной работы асинхронной функции, я не могу сохранить результат в переменные, которые были декларированы до использования асинхронной функции. Я знаю, что происходит в таких ситуациях, но как мне решить эту проблему и сохранять результаты в вышедекларированные переменные, я не знаю.

Пример такой вот проблемы:

Предположим, что у меня есть массив с определенной информацией для подключения к удаленному хосту:

```
// Hosts output
var Hosts = [{
    hostName  : 'test1',
    password  : 'pass1',
    ipAddress : '192.168.0.1',
}, {
    hostName  : 'test2',
    password  : 'pass2',
    ipAddress : '192.168.0.2',
}, {
    hostName  : 'test3',
    password  : 'pass3',
    ipAddress : '192.168.0.3',
}];
```

в моем случаи, их `3`.

Для того, чтобы подключиться к удаленному хосту, я использую [simple-ssh](https://www.npmjs.com/package/simple-ssh) модуль. Прежде чем подключиться к хосту, нужно создать сессию для каждого хоста. Делаю я это таким вот образом:

```
...

var SshSessions = [];
var  index = 0, len = 0;
for (index = 0, len = Hosts.length; index < len; ++index) {
    var sshSession = new ssh({
        user    : Hosts[index].hostName,
        pass    : Hosts[index].password,
        host    : Hosts[index].ipAddress,
        timeout : 3000
    });
    SshSessions.push(sshSession);
}

index = 0;
len   = 0;
for (index = 0, len = SshSessions.length; index < len; ++index) {
    SshSessions[index].exec('Любая команда', {
        out : function (stdout) {},
        err : function (stderr) {},
        exit: function (code)   {}
    }).start();
}
```

И тут у меня появляются проблемы. Моя задача, это выполнить определенную команду на удаленном хосте благодаря `ssh` сессии, и сохранить полученный результат в `MySql`. Так как `SshSession` работает асинхронно, я вызываю сохранения полученного результата в `out`:

```
for (index = 0, len = SshSessions.length; index < len; ++index) {
    SshSessions[index].exec('Любая команда', {
        out : function (stdout) {
            connection.query('Любая заявка SQL'), function(err, result) {
            ...
            })
        },
        err : function (stderr) {},
        exit: function (code)   {}
    }).start();
}
```

В самой заявке, я должен подать `ipAddress` хоста. Но при подаче его таким  вот образом:

```
out: function (stdout) {
     connection.query('call updateHost(' + SshSessions[index].host + ', ' + stdout + ')'), function(err, result) {
        //console.log(stdout); 
        if (err) {
           console.log(err);
        }
    });
},
```

у меня выходит ошибка, так как - `SshSessions[index].host` = `undefined`.

Каким образом нужно передавать аргументы, да и вообще работать с асинхронными методами, чтобы не было таких вот проблем. В моем случаи, я сначала создаю `ssh` сессию, после чего получаю результат от отправленной команды, и лишь после получения результата, отправляю этот результат по данному хосту в `MySQL` базу данных.

PS. Буду очень благодарен, если предоставите пример создания правильной структуры работы с асинхронными методами. В интернете смотрел многие примеры - но они мне ясности не дали.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для работы с асинхронными функциями/кодом можно использовать Promise API/(Async/Await).

Хорошие примеры есть [здесь](https://learn.javascript.ru/promise)

Попробуйте так:

```
(async() => {
        var SshSessions = [];
        var  index = 0, len = 0;
        for (index = 0, len = Hosts.length; index < len; ++index) {
            var sshSession = new ssh({
                user    : Hosts[index].hostName,
                pass    : Hosts[index].password,
                host    : Hosts[index].ipAddress,
                timeout : 3000
            });
            SshSessions.push(sshSession);
        }
    
        index = 0;
        len   = 0;
        for (index = 0, len = SshSessions.length; index < len; ++index) {
            await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                SshSessions[index].exec('Любая команда', {
                    out: function (stdout) {
                         connection.query('call updateHost(' + SshSessions[index].host + ', ' + stdout + ')'), function(err, result) {
                            //console.log(stdout); 
                            if (err) {
                               console.log(err);
                            }
                            resolve();
                        });
                    },
                    err : function (stderr) {},
                    exit: function (code)   {}
                }).start();
            });
        }
})();
```

Ключевое слово `await` приостановит цикл пока функция внутри promise не вызовет `resolve()`. И в таком случае  `SshSessions[index].exec()` будут выполнятся по очереди.

Comment: Спасибо большое за пример. А что на счет `connection.query`, ведь она тоже является асинхронной функцией. Для нее так же нужно использовать Promise или нет ?

Comment: в данном случае по идее нет, тк resolve вызывается в ней, соответственно пока она не выполнится, промис будет в состоянии pending и цикл будет ожидать его выполнения для продолжения. Пока код внутри промиса не вызовет Reject/Resolve цикл будет ждать.

Comment: Проверил у себя - Вы првы :)